# Trying to get Python Graphics with text to voice application working

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using python3 with Tkinter but I can't get over that i need a mainloop() statemment to get the screen to pop up and draw, then only by closing the graphics screen will the program then go on to the text to speak section. How can I have my graphics displayed without the program halting?

Comment: Look into the `threading` or `multiprocessing` modules (the second one should prefereably be used if your tts is implemented in C)

Comment: Thanks Jim, that's a useful tip:  :-)